Producing solo work
For context I am in pure mathematics and I just started my first postdoc.
I am worried that I cannot produce solo work. I have a fair number of papers so far which are all collaborations with peers and/or some more senior people in my field, and I think all these are decent papers, and that I contributed substantially to each of these. I would like to produce some work on my own however, but I feel that all the problems that I can pin-point are either too easy to be considered a good result or too hard for me to address.
Has anyone here struggled with similar problems in the past? Any advice for such a situation, or how to build the skill of working solo? Not having single authored work makes me feel uncomfortable and less confident about my skills.

Do any of your papers build upon prior papers of yours?  Have you written a paper with some coauthors and then written another paper that built upon it with other coauthors?  When you attend talks by other people in your area, can you come up with good questions to ask that are about potential future work?  Do you have any ideas for new approaches to any of the bigger problems in your field?

I don't think having solo papers is necessarily that important (though it is a problem if all your papers are with the same few collaborators, which doesn't seem to be the case for you).  However, your question does point to a different problem which will eventually affect you if you don't develop your skills, which is that a tenure-track (or at least a tenured) professor at a PhD granting department needs to come up with good problems for their grad students to work on.

I think it would be useful to know why you think that you want to write solo papers? I believe that out of the 70-or-so publications I have, only one or two are solo papers. I just don't find it particularly interesting to work on my own -- I much more enjoy working with others, and I think that there is nothing wrong with this approach. (Nor has anyone ever "encouraged" me to write more solo papers.)

@AlexanderWoo to answer your questions, i haven't build upon the papers i have so far, this is what i plan to do. About talks, the plain answer is: sometimes, and about the big problems, I don't have concrete ideas, only thoughts around these

@WolfgangBangerth even though i agree with you mostly, i think i need to write solo papers to feel like I'm capable of doing research on my own, and at the same time prove that to the rest of the community I guess. It's mostly a feeling I suppose

I am confident that "the rest of the community" by and large has very little interest in tracking how many solo papers you have. I mean, do you often find yourself scrutinizing how many solo papers a given researcher has and judging them based on this? If so, you should probably stop. If not, why do you imagine that other people are doing this?

@AdamPřenosil I sometimes look to see how many solo papers people I'm interested in have written. It seems to me a legitimate thing to wonder about, and provides some useful ideas about their approach to research and their level of independence. (I also realize it's not a perfect metric and should not be relied on as an indicator of some kind of absolute truth about the person; no metric is. But being imperfect does not mean it is completely useless information.) Since you say that I "should probably stop", can you explain what's wrong with my interest?

@DanRomik I am sure that one can figure out many things from someone's patterns of collaboration (such as overreliance on some senior figure). What I was trying to suggest is that I don't think much of this information comes from looking at the number of authors only. If you imagine looking at the list of publications of someone you don't know where all the information about co-authors except their number has been erased, I would find it hard to use this limited information to distinguish solid researchers who like to collaborate from researchers who lack independence.

@DanRomik (Though in the other direction, a solo paper in a Very Good Journal presumably does count as confirmation of research independence.) But sure, if you are finding "number of solo papers" a useful metric in practice, then who am I to say you should stop. The advice was meant for someone who seems overly concerned about their number of solo papers though their patterns of collaboration seem fine.


I would like to produce some work on my own however, but I feel that all the problems that I can pin-point are either too easy to be considered a good result or too hard for me to address.

Have you actually tried to do solo work? I can think of three scenarios depending on your answer to this.

If you haven't tried to do solo work, then the answer is simple: try it! What I mean is, don't just spend time agonizing over your lack of solo publications and ruling out candidate problems you can think of as being either too easy to be interesting, or too hard to be solvable. Pick an actual, concrete problem, and spend actual, concrete (and significant) time trying to solve it, and writing up the solution or any ideas you come up with. What sometimes happens is you don't solve the original problem, but you come up with something else that's interesting and possibly publishable. That's why working on very difficult problems, or even on very easy problems, isn't always the waste of time that some people imagine it to be.

If you did try to do solo work, look back on what happened and consider the possibility that you only think you tried, and you didn't really Try with a capital T. Was your attempt half-hearted? Did you give up too easily because you found the problem too hard or headache-inducing? Or did you get bored quickly because you found the problem too trivial, ruling it out as something that wouldn't interest anyone or that you would be embarrassed to publish? (Note: I'm not saying that your judgment in either of these cases would necessarily be wrong; some problems are too hard, and other problems are too boring. I'm merely asking you to critique your thought process, looking for places where your judgment may be worth revisiting.)

If you did Try (with a capital T) to do solo work, and you still didn't succeed, then... you should know that that's actually pretty normal! This is actually what happens around 90% of the time when I try to do solo work. (Those 10% of the times when I did succeed led to my solo publications, which represent about half of my entire research output.) So the thing to remember is that doing successful research in mathematics is just really hard. You need to try many times to get one success. And each individual attempt should typically require a real, serious, concerted effort.


A final thought: in my experience, some people are technically brilliant and can do very good collaborative work, but lack the sort of creative spark that can lead them to identify the sort of "tasty" problems to work on that lead to good solo work. So as others said, it may be useful to keep in mind that doing good solo work isn't entirely necessary to be a successful researcher or to have a good academic career.

It is hard to judge the difficulty of a math problem before you attack it. Some things that seem easy are hard and the opposite is also true.
But there is no reason to work on a single problem at a time. Having a few problems "in progress" is a good thing and switching between them is a good approach based on how the brain works.
Perhaps you could write up drafts of the "easy" problems and show them to a few colleagues for comment on impact. Perhaps they will find them non-trivial, in which case they might be worth submitting while you work on the harder things. The feedback you get will, in any case, help you firm your judgement on the quality of those problems and solutions.
But, collaboration is a good thing in math. Ask Erdős or any of his collaborators.

Alongside his extremely prolific collaboration, Erdős wrote over 400 solo papers.

This is a stage that one can pass through. I had relatively few solo papers early in my career, and the ones I did have were served up to me on a silver platter by my mentors. (I did the work myself, but they gave me the project ideas in a very well-defined form.) Like you, I worried about my ability to work in a self-directed way. What I found eventually was that this skill kind of develops on its own with time.
Keep doing research, and keep talking to senior people around you about research problems. Keep thinking up your own project ideas, and gradually they will get better. i.e. they'll be worth doing and also approachable with your toolkit. (It helps that your toolkit will also grow.)
Another thing that helped me was being forced to write grant proposals. I couldn't just ask my mentors what I should put in the proposal, so I had to come up with future research questions myself. My first couple of proposals were very bad. But I got better at it, and occasionally my proposals even get funded.
These days, producing solo papers isn't strictly necessary to have a successful research career. However, the ability to identify important but doable research problems IS important, whether you end up working on these problems by yourself or with others. And this ability comes with time. One day you'll realize you have too many ideas for projects, and not enough time to work on them all.

Not only with time, but specifically with developing concentrated expertise.  Considering the OP hasn't yet written a paper that builds upon one of their prior papers, they haven't quite gotten to this point yet.  This isn't unusual for someone who has just finished their PhD, even among those whose PhDs were successful enough for them to obtain a postdoc position.

Well, currently, multi-author papers in math seem to be the norm, unlike some decades ago. In part, this is surely due to the ease of long-distance communication "in modern times". :)
And, yes, it is generally easier and happier to not necessarily work in a vacuum, but, rather, have someone else to bounce ideas off.
Nevertheless, when you'd come up for tenure, having no solo papers provides a target for anyone wanting to argue against you.

Completely agree

The last sentence is true, but people who want to argue against someone will always find a reason to do so; so I don't think this is a good reason to strive for solo papers.
